# SEO - ID CLASS Names

Tags: seo

is there any value in name ID and Class names with keywords for SEO?

eg: instead of

```
        <div id="bodywrapper">
```

you could use

```
        <div id="seoword-bodywrapper">
```

thoughts?

thx

Comment: Pretty much anything not visible to the user has been so thoroughly polluted by the SEO blackhats that no search engine pays attention to them for ranking.

Comment: I'm closing this question as off-topic because it is not about a practical programming problem as outlined in the [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 7):

No; design your website for humans, not computers. Search engines care about how users will see your website, so the markup is immaterial. Furthermore, the number of bytes on a page actually impacts the time it takes to load the page; so, from an SEO perspective, you are even better off using small-ish IDs that save more bytes at page loading time than using longer ids that could add user-visible latency.

Answer (score 4):

To the best of my knowledge, neither Google nor any web design best practices have ever suggested that element IDs have any such significance.

Answer (score 3):

Nice, what we all know is search search read html of a webpage and if it finds more keywords in html as form of ID/Class then it can help ranking. Nice thing to look into.

Answer (score 2):

No, Search engines want to view and index your pages as per how the users see it. For example, you can use this easy tool to preview your page (**text-only**) exactly as how the Search Engine would see it.

It has long been agreed, black hat SEO is worthless but people still make money off of clients for the same with large promises. **Content** still wins the battle everytime.

Replace the `http://domain.com` below with your domain and you can easily preview what needs to be highlighted and whats a waste of time.

```
http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:http://domain.com/&strip=1&vwsrc=0
```

Answer (score 2):

No You Can't; As we all knew the Guideline of Google, We have to design our website as per the human not for the Computer Language. Search Engine like Google, Bing and other Search Engine can only understand what ever the Content you are writing its for the human and if you will focus your content for the Search Engine Instead of human then you can achieve the goal and its not for the perspective of SEO.

Please Check out some of the popular referral blog related to the SEO terms of Use.

http://www.searchenginejournal.com/10-seo-tips-youd-surprised-didnt-know/145008/

http://www.vidhiwebsolutions.com/seo-tips/

If still you are facing any problem let me know I will try to get help you.

Answer (score 1):

As per my 4 years of experience, not any benefit to put keywords in "id".

Answer (score 0):

Element id's are used by developer for certain purpose such as if i have a form on my website and i am writing a function in java script to clear its fields, then i need to provide an id to that function for accessing that field. It has nothing to do with SEO and neither any search engine look for element ids.

Answer (score 0):

No, it will never help... If you see cached page in Search Engines they remove all your styles only basic html elements like heading, paragraph, anchor etc. are countable.

Answer (score 0):

In short, there is no value. The id is used as a unique id for an HTML element and should not be a target. You should avoid keyword stuffing as this will bring you far down the ranks. However, that being said using the keyword in the "right" places will help such as in your title tag, url and header tags are beneficial but not to be overused! Having the right balance is key while having it read naturally. Do not keep the keyword density high in your content and use LSI keywords instead to ensure quality.

Comment: Do you have any source / proof for this? If yes please update you answer